# register raspberry as gateway and senseHat as device on watson iot

Tags: raspberry-pi, iot, gateway, node-red, watson-iot

I am doing a coursera mooc.
I registered my raspberry pi as a gateway and as a senseHat device in my watson iot platform.
We can only define one device in `/etc/iotsample-raspberrypi/device.cfg`. I tried both but only the senseHat manages to register.
[Watson IoT Devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLB7R.png)
Then when connecting my raspberryPi as a gateway in Node-red it keep on failing with message:

> 15/12/2016 à 11:25:21msg : string [49]IBMIoT: Error: Connection
>   refused: Not authorized
>   I created an IoT node in my Raspberry node-red:
>   [gateway node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Pgbl.png)

So what is the correct way to connect the senseHat onto my raspberry pi as a device and raspberry pi as gateway both in watson iot platform?

Answer (score 0):

What credentials do you use to connect the PI in NodeRed? It should work fine if you connect it using an API Key and API Token.

Comment: I am using API Token for both (btw the same token)

Comment: Marc, if you can provide your 6 character org for your IoT service we may be able to confirm in the logs what credentials are failing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it. What I did (some step might not be necessary but doing this worked fine for me):
1. Remove any node in node-red using the device or gateway
2. Used the senHat device in :

```
/etc/iotsample-raspberrypi/device.cfg
```

3. stoped iot and nodered:

```
sudo service iot stop
node-red-stop
```

4. started both iot and nodered
5. added the nodes in nodered

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with this and struggled for about an hour. Sounds dumb, but if you are copying your credentials (I did so when following the online tutorial), it might introduce a space character before them in node-red. It was so small I didn't realize after a while, but it was keeping me from logging in.